# sqalchemy update bindparam primary key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, asyncpg

The following code throws "sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Unconsumed column names: _id".

```
User = Table('users', metadata,
 Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
 Column('score', Integer)
)

values = [
    {'score': 2, '_id': 1},
    {'score': 3, '_id': 3}
]
query = User.update().where(User.c.id == bindparam('_id')).values(score=bindparam('score'))
await db.execute_many(query, values)
```

`db` is an instance of [databases](https://www.encode.io/databases/).`Database`. Notice that I have to the name '_id' because SQLalchemy says 'id' is reserved.

Is there any solution other than updating each row individullay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Database.execute_many()` calls `Connection.execute_many()` which breaks your query up into separate individual queries (one per element in `values`), here's the method ([source](https://github.com/encode/databases/blob/f916dbbedceb0740c3708251c90a4f84108c3757/databases/core.py#L242-L247)):

```py
    async def execute_many(
        self, query: typing.Union[ClauseElement, str], values: list
    ) -> None:
        queries = [self._build_query(query, values_set) for values_set in values]
        async with self._query_lock:
            await self._connection.execute_many(queries)
```

Note that it calls the `_build_query()` method ([source](https://github.com/encode/databases/blob/f916dbbedceb0740c3708251c90a4f84108c3757/databases/core.py#L266-L277)):

```py
    @staticmethod
    def _build_query(
        query: typing.Union[ClauseElement, str], values: dict = None
    ) -> ClauseElement:
        if isinstance(query, str):
            query = text(query)

            return query.bindparams(**values) if values is not None else query
        elif values:
            return query.values(**values)

        return query
```

As you aren't passing a `str` query and you are passing values, control enters the `elif values:` condition handling where the individual dict of values is unpacked into the `.values()` method on your query (which is [`Update.values()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Update.values)). That essentially makes the query it's trying to compile this:

```py
query = (
    User.update()
    .where(User.c.id == bindparam("_id"))
    .values(score=bindparam("score"))
    .values(score=2, _id=1)
)
```

That second values clause results in a new Update with new bind params that are trying to set values for both `score` and `_id`. This causes compilation of the query to fail as there is no `_id` column on the table.

So the MCVE to reproduce the error is really this:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

User.update().values(score=2, _id=1).compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect())
```

Which raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\main.py", line 31, in <module>
    User.update().values(score=2, _id=1).compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect())
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "C:\Users\peter\Documents\git\stackoverflow\58668615-sqalchemy-update-bindparam-primary-key\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 462, in compile
    return self._compiler(dialect, bind=bind, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\peter\Documents\git\stackoverflow\58668615-sqalchemy-update-bindparam-primary-key\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 468, in _compiler
    return dialect.statement_compiler(dialect, self, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\peter\Documents\git\stackoverflow\58668615-sqalchemy-update-bindparam-primary-key\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 571, in __init__
    Compiled.__init__(self, dialect, statement, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\peter\Documents\git\stackoverflow\58668615-sqalchemy-update-bindparam-primary-key\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 319, in __init__
    self.string = self.process(self.statement, **compile_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\peter\Documents\git\stackoverflow\58668615-sqalchemy-update-bindparam-primary-key\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 350, in process
    return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\peter\Documents\git\stackoverflow\58668615-sqalchemy-update-bindparam-primary-key\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 92, in _compiler_dispatch
    return meth(self, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\peter\Documents\git\stackoverflow\58668615-sqalchemy-update-bindparam-primary-key\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 2569, in visit_update
    self, update_stmt, crud.ISUPDATE, **kw
  File "C:\Users\peter\Documents\git\stackoverflow\58668615-sqalchemy-update-bindparam-primary-key\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\crud.py", line 62, in _setup_crud_params
    return _get_crud_params(compiler, stmt, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\peter\Documents\git\stackoverflow\58668615-sqalchemy-update-bindparam-primary-key\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\crud.py", line 177, in _get_crud_params
    % (", ".join("%s" % c for c in check))
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Unconsumed column names: _id
```

To summarise the issue, you build a query with bind params passed to both `Update.where()` and `Update.values()`. You then pass that query and your values to `Database.execute_many()` where they unpack the individual elements of your values list into a second call of `Update.values()` on your query which replaces your query with one that tries to set a value for an `_id` column which doesn't exist.

> Is there any solution other than updating each row individullay?

Well the query works just fine when using sqlalchemy engine as well as query:

```py
# using a sqlalchemy engine
engine.execute(query, values)
```

Otherwise, what should work is sending the query in as a string to `Database.execute_many()` as that will mean the query gets handled in the `if isinstance(query, str):` part of the `_build_query()` method which will avoid the second `.values()` call being made on the query:

```py
db.execute_many(str(query), values)
```